# Vuex Getter Undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I am new to Vue.js and experiencing an issue with Vuex modules and Axios. I have a "post" component that retrieves a slug from the router and fetches data with Axios which is then retrieved with Vuex Getters.

I am able to retrieve data successfully but then I still see this error on my DevTools, **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"**

Due to this error I am not able to pass `this.post.name` to Vue-Meta.

**Codes**

Post.vue

```
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["post"]),
  },

  mounted() {
    const slug = this.$route.params.slug;
    this.fetchPost({ slug: slug });
  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["fetchPost"]),
```

/store/modules/post.js

```
const state = {
  post: [],
};

const getters = {
  post: (state) => {
    return post;
  }
};

const actions = {
  async fetchPost({ commit }, arg) {
    try {
      await axios.get("/post/" + arg.slug).then((response) => {
        commit("setPost", response.data);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setPost: (state, post) => (state.post = post),
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your getter is utterly wrong: a state getter is supposed to be a function that takes in the entire `state` as a param and retrieves whatever you're interested in from it. Your version...

```
const getters = {
  post: (state) => {
   return post;
  }
};
```

...takes in the `state` as a param but doesn't use it. Instead, it returns a variable (`post`) which has not been defined in that context.
Which will always return `undefined`, regardless of current value of `state.post`.
And, as you already know, JavaScript can't access property `'name'` of `undefined`.

To get the current value of `state.post`, use:

```
const getters = {
  post: state => state.post
}
```

Or

```
const getters = {
  post: (state) => { return state.post; }
}
```

... if you fancy brackets.

Also, out of principle, I suggest initializing your post with an empty object `{}` instead of an empty array `[]`.
Changing variable types as few times as possible is a very good coding habit, providing huge benefits in the long run.

---

**Edit** (after [mcve])

You have a bigger problem: the import from your axios plugin returns `undefined`. So you can't call `get` on it. Because you wrapped that call into a `try/catch` block, you don't get to see the error but the endpoint is never called.
I don't know where you picked that plugin syntax from but it's clearly not exporting axios. Replacing the import with `import axios from 'axios'` works as expected.

Another advice would be to `namespace` your store module. That's going to become useful when you'll have more than one module and you'll want to specifically reference a particular mutation/action on a specific module. You'll need to slightly change `mapActions` and `mapGetters` at that point.

See it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-newton-86jor?file=/src/App.vue).

Comment: @0x0, it's time you created a [mcve]. Use codesandbox.io or similar.

Comment: could you please have a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sid-rw927

Comment: First time using Codesandbox, please pardon my ignorance. Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Having a getter return `undefined` regardless of state value looks like a real enough error to me. Glad I could be of help. Happy coding!